# Keep getting an error when trying to place button from Semantic UI into code. error is Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, semantic-ui

I am trying to work on this side project I am using with a MERNG stack. The issue I am getting is when I am trying to add a button from my semantic UI react documents into my code. The button I am trying to add is from this source https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/#types-labeled-basic-shorthand. Whenever I try to implement that code I get that error and I do not know exactly why my error is occuring. My GitHub Repo is https://github.com/Hoybaby/React-Social-App. I am currently Hiding my config.js which is the connection to my database with a secret key being secret key. Please Help. [Image of Code in PostCard.js in components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uois6.png).

The error is this. [Error On Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRe8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365405/react-16-error-unable-to-find-node-on-an-unmounted-component) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734483/reactdom-render-unable-to-find-node-on-an-unmounted-component-after-react-upgra).
I would suggest trying to update all the dependencies - I see no clear source of that error, however lots of your dependencies are deprecated.

Comment: All the dependencies I used for example react, was simply created with npx  create-react-app client. And then the dependencies on the front end were simply installed with something similar like this "npm install graphql graphql-tag". Not sure how they would be exactly deprecated.

Comment: Also I am not using componentDidMounts as I am using function components. so The first link you suggest I don't think can be used to help solve this. I am still a freshly new web developer with 6 months experience so not sure if I am missing something trivial.